# IMVFH is compressed - meaning?

Tags: windows-7, boot, filesystem-corruption

Windows 7 SP1, fully updated every Tuesday when MS ships them, on an old Q9800 quad which has ticked along nicely for years with very little on it except a couple of automated low-impact tasks I have it doing.

I'm not certain exactly what I did to trigger this - though I did click to start "Compress this drive to save disk space" & then changed my mind in the first few seconds of it building the catalogue.
Nothing errored at the time & it seemed to just cancel cleanly.

The next boot, I got the message

> IMVFH is compressed
>   Hold Ctrl/Alt/Del to restart

& that was it.
No amount of fiddling in what little I know of Windows Repair structures would fix it.
I couldn't get to Safe Boot or Last Known Good etc, so I attempted automatic repair from a Windows boot USB with a full installer. No difference. Restore to a recent Restore Point, completed successfully, no difference. As far as I'm aware, you can't do a full repair install on WIn7 from outside the running OS without destroying the existing installation, so I didn't attempt that. [I'm Mac-based mostly, so some of my Windows chops are a tad rusty.]

I eventually gave up & just restored the whole thing from this morning's backup<sup>[1]</sup>, so I can't go back to test theories.

I just wondered if anyone knows quite what that error was. Google came up with absolutely nothing, for the entire phrase, or even the prime component of it 'IMVFH'.

<sup>[1]</sup> I can't give anyone else dirty looks for not having a backup if I don't practise what I preach ;-)

Comment: A strange error. Have you tried to decompress the whole drive from an Windows recovery command-line? `compact /s /u c:\ ` (or what ever drive name is correct in the recovery console).

Comment: Just because you cancelled the compression doe not mean it undoes what is already compressed, it compressed a critical boot file, hence the error. I have no clue why W7 ever offered a user to compress files to save disk space, it was from back in the day when disk space was a premium due to very small hard drives. I never use this feature.

Comment: @Robert That is indeed the correct way to undo a partial (and cancelled) full-disk compress. (No matter how short it had actually run.) You either do it immediately after the cancel or you will have to do it from the recovery console using a different boot-medium.

Comment: Terrible error-trapping if it will let a user do that & immediately kill their chances of getting back in. I'm afraid I can't go back to test the theory, but it does make sense. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal error message is:

```
BOOTMGR is compressed
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

The Windows VBR has very basic support for reading NTFS, in order to load the main boot manager out of `\BOOTMGR`. It becomes unable to read that file if it has NTFS-level compression enabled (or is literally anything other than a completely normal, contiguous file).

If the message has a different file name, then either the partition's VBR is corrupted (it might be looking for the wrong file entirely), or the memory area containing the message got corrupted while it was trying to interpret the filesystem.

The usual `bootrec /fixboot` and `/fixmbr` from a recovery console might help.